# Rendering a combo box in a partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, partial-views

In my project i have this combo box, and it works perfectly:

```
<%= collection_select @project, @project.clients.id, @project.clients, :id, :name %>
```

My simple and quick question is, how can i render this in a partial, I'm using this and it's not working...

```
<%= render :partial => "clients", :collection => @project.clients, :locals => {:project => @project }%>
```

and the partial code is:

```
<%= collection_select :project, clients.id, clients, clients.id, clients.name %
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this within your partial:

```
<%= collection_selection project, project.clients.id, project.clients, :id, :name %>
```

(When you refer to template instance variables that are passed in to the partial as locals, use the non-symbol form of the variable name.)